# How to prevent open my application more than one time?

Tags: c#, winforms, single-instance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to create a single instance application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application)

How can I define my application to open only one time after click on its exe file over and over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always done this at the application's entry point:

```
bool onlyInstance = false;

Mutex m = new Mutex(true, "MyUniqueMutextName", out onlyInstance);
if (!onlyInstance)
{
    return;
}

GC.KeepAlive(m);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several related questions on Stack Overflow for [Single Instance Applications](https://www.google.com/search?q=single%20instance%20application%20C#):

This one seems to be the most apropriate: [What is the correct way to create a single-instance application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application)